# JFrame is not showing up in ubuntu

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu

When I run this code in ubuntu, the window is minimized. When I click on it's icon, it stays minimized.
But it's working fine in Windows.

Here's my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton b = new JButton("Button 1");
        p.add(b);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("TestFrame");
        f.add(p);

        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500,500);
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: f.pack() ? should do the trick

Comment: You need to call either `f.pack()` or. `f.setSize(...)` **before** `f.setVisible(true)`. `setVisible()` should be the last line when making your GUI visible... That's what I can see at first view but can't test since I don't have Ubuntu installed here

Comment: Swing/AWT GUIs should be started on the Event Dispatch Thread. It might not be the problem here, but use best practices anyway. Also, as mentioned by @mko we should use `pack()` to size the GUI, after all the components are added, but before `setVisible(true)`. Remove `f.setSize(500,500);` - it is just a guess.

Comment: There's nothing especially wrong with your code (but I agree with Andrew, you should start the UI on the EDT) and I can't replicate your issue

Answer (score 1):

Put `f.setSize(500, 500);` between  `JFrame f = new JFrame("TestFrame");` and `f.add(p);`. You can't call `f.setVisible(true);` before the JFrame is fully builded and initialized. Also I recommend to use a LayoutManager in a JPanel/JFrame such as BorderLayout.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout(0, 0);
        p.setLayout(bl);

        JButton b = new JButton("Button 1");
        p.add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("TestFrame");
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.getContentPane().add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"You can't call f.setVisible(true); before the JFrame is fully builded"* - you can, but you need to revalidate and repaint the component. *"Also I recommend to use a LayoutManager in a JPanel/JFrame such as BorderLayout."* - All window based classes default to a `BorderLayout`; We haven't had to use `getContentPane().add` since what, Java 1.6, `JFrame#add` forwards the call to the `contentPane`; Changing the size of the window after it's been made visible should have no bearing on the results, other then perhaps making the frame look like it's "popped" when it's first loaded